# A question regarding connected subsets of connected metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a connected metric space and let $C$ be a connected subset of $X$. Let $X-C$ be a union of two separated sets $A$ and $B$. It is required to show that $C\cup A$ and $C\cup B$ are both connected. I've no idea how to approach this problem, being a beginner in this concept. Any solutions will be highly appreciated.